# Is .NET 3.5 framework supported if my Windows Server 2012 R2 is upgraded to Windows Server 2022?

Tags: .net, windows

I would like to understand the support of .NET Framework 3.5. My applications are running on .NET 3.5 on a Windows 2012 R2 server.

Our IT team is upgrading the server to 2022 R2. What are the necessary steps should I take to make my application should work?

Has the .NET 3.5 FW support already ended? How is .NET 3.5 SP1 different from .NET 3.5? I need the detailed clarification.